# Link a img id="logo"

Tags: html, css

I have - img id="logo" SO I can have my logo on my website, the full code for it being:

```
<img id="logo" src="nsc/logo2.png" alt="logo" />
```

How can I link this logo image using `<a href="">` ???

I've tried many different ways but they don't work :/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Congratulations on asking a well structured question with a code example, keep it up!

Answer (score 9):

```
<a href="www.example.com"><img id="logo" src="nsc/logo2.png" alt="logo" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be nice to embed in a link tag. :)

```
<a href="your.html">
    <img id="logo" src="nsc/logo2.png" alt="BrandLog" />
</a>
```

it's clean and no need of javascript :)

Answer (score 1):

It's super simple, just wrap the `<img>` tag with an anchor tag `<a>`:

```
<a href="myUrl.html">
    <img id="logo" src="nsc/logo2.png" alt="logo" />
</a>
```

This will turn the entire image into a link for you :)

Answer (score 1):

For people who want to receive click event on `a` tag instead of `img` tag

```html
<a href="/chat" style="background: red; display: inline-block;">
  <img src="chat.svg" style="pointer-events: none; display: block;" width=40 height=40>
</a>
```

On `a` tag

- `display: inline-block` in `a`: allows to set a width and height on `a` tag

On `img` tag

- `display: block`: help remove extra space below the image
- `pointer-events: none`: ignore click on `img`, click event will fired on `a` tag

Answer (score 0):

If you can't wrap the image in a link, an image map should work just as well without requiring JavaScript & without needing to wrap the element.

Answer (score -1):

I add id in img tag like this:

```
  <img id={logo.id} src={logo.url} onError={this.handleImageError} />
```

Since I am working on React that's why I used JSX in the id and src attribute. onError attribute is used if the image is broken. It gives me an event, So this is how I access the id attribute:

```
handleImageError = (e) => { console.log(e.target.id) }
```

Answer (score -6):

Here is the solution for you,

```
<img id="logo" src="nsc/logo2.png" alt="logo" onClick="window.open('http://yahoo.com');" />
```

Comment: baaaad. there's no reason to use javascript here

Comment: Reasons this is "bad": The user can't a) right-click to copy the link, b) mouse-over to see where the link goes before clicking, c) middle-click to (or right-click and) open in a new tab.