# Add link to logo - Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to add a link back to the home page index.php from my logo,

Cant figure it out. Appreciate any assistance,

Thanks

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:black;"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/logo.png" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;"></div>
```

Comment: Wrap img tag in an anchor tag like this` <a href="/"><img src=""></a>`

Comment: ^ just like I said; HTML 101. https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link a img id=“logo”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085053/link-a-img-id-logo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link a img id="logo"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085053/link-a-img-id-logo)

Answer (score 0):

Bill04,

You can wrap a  tag around the image logo, like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:black;">
    <a href="index.php"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/logo.png" data-bs-hover-animate="pulse" style="padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px;"></a>
</div>
```

Hope it works!
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks , but my was hoping just to have the logo linked , This code makes the whole header linked. Thanks and appreciate the help.